# SQL view with date calculations

Tags: sql

I have a database that tracks the location of inventory.

The application was poorly written and is a mess of spaghetti code with no MVC separation and updates to the model can happen in any number of files.

When the application was first written it only needed to track the location the inventory currently resides in so a SiteID column exists in the inventory table that lists it's currently assigned to.

Since then the owner has decided he wants to maintain a history of which locations the inventory is assigned to. Rather than trawl through all the code to try and find all the places it possibly updates I added a trigger `ON UPDATE`and `ON INSERT` to the inventory table that records movements in a history table.

The initial requirement was to be able to view the movement history of a piece of inventory which is easily solved with `SELECT * FROM history WHERE InvID = X ORDER BY timestamp DESC`

Now I've been asked to produce a list for a given location that shows when a piece of inventory is assigned to the site, and the date it leaves (example below). Ideally I'd like to achieve this without modifying the existing schema and triggers if possible.

I'm able to retrieve a list of all the inventory that was assigned to the site at one point and the date which it was assigned. What I'm struggling with is how to find the date that piece of inventory left the site. I could do it within the application but I wondered if it's possible with SQL.

**Inventory table**

```
InventoryID     InventoryName    SiteID
===========     =============    ======
          1     Widget A         $ID
          2     Widget B         $ID
          3     Widget C         $ID
```

**Locations table**

```
SiteID    SiteName
======    ========
     1    Somewhere
     2    Nowhere
     3    Anywhere
```

**History table**

```
InvID    SiteID    Timestamp
=====    ======    =========
    1         1    2012-01-01
    1         2    2012-01-02
    2         1    2012-01-03
    1         1    2012-01-04
```

**New view should look something like this**

```
InvID    DateIn        DateOut
=====    ==========    ==========
    1    2012-01-01    2012-01-02
    2    2012-01-03    NULL
    1    2012-01-04    NULL
```

**Psuedo code to produce table with a programming language (post-processing SQL query**

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE SiteID = 1

foreach (row in result) {
    DateOut = SELECT * FROM history WHERE InvID = result.InvID AND timestamp > result.timestamp LIMIT 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

Its just possible with left outer join to the same table and take the min date from the right table

```
select H1.InvID,I.InventoryName,H1.SiteID,H1.[Timestamp] [date in],
MIN(H2.[Timestamp]) [date out] 
from    History H1 left outer join History H2
on      H1.InvID=H2.InvID and H1.[Timestamp]<H2.[Timestamp]
join Inventory I on I.InventoryID= H1.InvID
where   H1.SiteID=1
group by    H1.InvID,I.InventoryName,H1.SiteID,H1.[Timestamp]
```

[Sql Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bce2/1)

Comment: Is it possible to expand this to include the inventory name in the results?  

    InvID    InvName    DateIn        DateOut  
    =====    =======    ==========    ==========  
        1    Widget A   2012-01-01    2012-01-02  
        2    Widget B   2012-01-03    NULL 
        1    Widget A   2012-01-04    NULL

Comment: @mcourtney: Very much possible. I have updated my query. please check it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to find the first date where the inventory item is at a different site:

```
select  h1.InvID
,       h1.Timestamp as DateIn
,       (
        select  min(TimeStamp)
        from    history h2
        where   h2.InvID = h1.InvID
                and h2.SiteID <> h1.SiteID
                and h2.TimeStamp > h1.TimeStamp
        ) as DateOut
from    history h1
where   h1.SiteID = X
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug in this. For inventory that only has one history entry (i.e. the initial assignment) there is still a DateOut listed (expected result is NULL)